# I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for FirebaseStorage on Android Plugin

Tags: java, android, firebase, plugins, firebase-storage

I'm working with FirebaseStorage on a plugin model.
I was able to make it work on a standalone android app, but when I try to add it to a plugin, I get the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Here is my build.gradle for the plugin.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {

        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
    repositories {
        google() // Make sure Google's Maven repository is added
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



android {
    namespace 'com.shefyg.uapaa1module'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1' // Firebase Core
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.1' // Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the versions from the Firebase dependencies since you are already sing BOM?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The plugin was for Unity and worked with unit activity.
It turned out I had to add Firebase to the Unity project.
Or I guess any other activity that would use the plugin.